# How to SEARCH on DATAGRIDVIEW by using 2 values on different TEXTBOX?

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code where in I want to search data on my datagridview by using 2 values on 2 different textboxes:

```
  else if (comboBox1.Text.Length > 0 && textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
  {
        SqlDataAdapter ada = 
           new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM vPurchist_50M_CreditLine_Combined WHERE DEALER like '" + comboBox1.Text + "%' AND Company_Code like '" + textBox2.Text + "%'",sqlCon);
        ada.Fill(dtbl);
  }
```

i want to search the DEALER and Company_Code at the same time.

I tried to use "OR" or "AND" operators on my else if statement but still it doesnt show what I need. Any ideas on what should I do?

Comment: There's a lot you likely need to address here, before you'll get some meaningful assistance.  You mention an "else if statement" in your question, but your example code doesn't have any "else if statement" in it.  You have a SELECT statement that you may mean you've tried using "AND" or "OR" in, without achieving your desired results ... you will likely need to include an example of your data, as well as an example of the textbox/combo values that you are trying to filter on.

Comment: In addition, the way you are building your SQL statement by concatenating the textbox/combobox values is considered bad practice - you should look at using parameterised statements to execute your SQL commands.  Eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-parameters

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your query returns results via a tool like SQL Server Management Studio.

You might then want to break your C# code into more manageable chunks so you can step thru each step with the debugger and pinpoint the issue. Start by putting your long SQL statement in a strSQL string variable. This string should be a parameterized statement as suggest by Craig. To specify the parameters values you will need to use the SQLCommand class. A USING block is recommended when a SQLCommand is employed.

```
  else if (comboBox1.Text.Length > 0 && textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
  {
        string strSQL= "SELECT * FROM vPurchist_50M_CreditLine_Combined WHERE DEALER like @DEALER + '%' AND Company_Code like @Company_Code + '%'";
 
            using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlCon))
            {
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@DEALER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
                sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Company_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);

                ada.Fill(dtbl);
            }
  }
```